# Json request with YQL and MooTools

Tags: javascript, json, mootools, yql

I'm working with some json files on another domain so I'm trying to make a crooss-domain request using YQL as proxy. I'm a beginner with javascript and web-technologies and every line of code I write could be much better, but for now it's not a problem if the code I write with your help is not that elegant.

For now my code is:

```
function GetUrl() {
    var link = "http://m.airpim.com/json/public/search?q=variabile&k=&e=1",
        name = document.id('s').get('value') || '*';

    return link.replace("variabile", name);
}

function Ricerca() {
    var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from json where url="' + GetUrl() + '"') + '&format=json&diagnostics=false&callback=';
    return yql;
}

function LavoroJson() {
    var ciao = new Request.JSONP({
        url: Ricerca(),
        onComplete: function(data) {
            // Log the result to console for inspection
            alert(ciao.toSource());
        }
    }).send();
}
```

In my idea I should do the request of the json using YQL, but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the Request.JSONP class somewhat.

```
Request.YQLJSON = new Class({
    // gets basic info such as country and latitude data
    Extends: Request.JSONP,

    options: {
        log: !true,
        url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22{location}%22&format=json"
    },

    initialize: function(location, options) {
        this.parent(options);
        if (!location)
            return;

        this.options.url = this.options.url.substitute({location: encodeURIComponent(location)});
    },

    success: function(data, script) {
        this.parent(data, script);
    }
});
```

and you can make your own DSL like implementation for the airpim particulars:

```
Request.airpim = new Class({

    Extends: Request.YQLJSON,

    options: {
        suburl: "http://m.airpim.com/json/public/search?q={search}&k=&e=1"
    },

    initialize: function(query, options) {
        this.parent(this.options.suburl.substitute({
            search: encodeURIComponent(query)
        }), options);
    }

});
```

use like so:

```
new Request.airpim("*", {
    onSuccess: function(data) {
        console.log(data.query.results.json);
    }
}).send();
```

https://tinker.io/c9634